# More efficient way to write this MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to speed this query up, and I am afraid it's impossible given the large amount of data.  But I decided I'll throw it out there and see if anyone has any suggestions.  I have two very simple tables:

**contractorList**

| id | contractor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John's Roofing |
| 2 | Mark's Roofing |

**form_submissions**

| id | contractor_id | submission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | ... |
| 3 | 1 | ... |
| 4 | 4 | ... |
| 5 | 1 | ... |
| 6 | 5 | ... |

...ETC

I am trying to get JUST the contractor name, id and **count** the number of submissions.  IE

```
SELECT a.id, a.contractor, count(b.contractor_id) AS submission_count
   FROM `contractorList` a
   LEFT JOIN contractor_form_submissions b
      ON b.contractor_id = a.id
   GROUP BY a.id
   ORDER BY a.contractor
```

The issue is that, I have about 1200 contractors ..  Run by itself is lightning quick.  But when I `LEFT JOIN` and `count()` their submissions (which can be in the thousands per contractor) the query grinds .. Like minutes, not seconds grinds.  Is there a more efficient SQL only route to obtain the count without the query taking forever?

**NOTE**
that `contractorList.id` AND `form_submissions.id` are both `PK` and `indexed`

Comment: Make sure that both `id` are primary keys and `contractor_id` is indexed.

Comment: I figured someone was going to mention that!  I included that in a note .. Yes the above is true ..

Comment: The index on `form_submissions.id` is irrelevant, you need an index on `contractor_id`. If it's declared as a foreign key this will be done automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to do the aggregation before joining, as this creates a smaller intermediate table.

```
SELECT a.id, a.contractor, IFNULL(b.submission_count, 0) AS submission_count
FROM contractorList AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT contractor_id, COUNT(*) AS submission_count
    FROM contractor_form_submissions
    GROUP BY contractor_id
) AS b ON a.id = b.contractor_id
ORDER BY a.contractor
```

Answer (score 1):

I could provide another SQL solution using related subquery which I learned from 《Effective SQL》.
Sample Query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WX7yN4GWRrA1wX7zb8AXv/0

```sql
SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.contractor,
    (
      select count(*)
      from contractor_form_submissions
      where contractor_form_submissions.contractor_id = a.id
    ) as submission_count
FROM contractor as a
order by a.id;
```

The query efficiency is based on the sql server and its own optimizer. So I am not sure whether this is more efficient or not comparing to JOIN solution.